# C++ Link Error Compiling With Macports gcc47

Tags: macos, eclipse-cdt, macports

I am writing a small app on Mac 10.7.5 with gcc47 via macports in Eclipse CDT to learn the new features in C++11. I have a large amount of code compiling, linking and running. When I add the call to "async" I get a linker error. The most simple program that will reproduce the link error follows. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

void bar()
{
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
}

int main() {
future<void> f1(async(bar));

return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
21:56:46 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Hello ****
make all
Building file: ../src/Hello.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler g++ -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -I/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Hello.d" -MT"src/Hello.d" -o "src/Hello.o" "../src/Hello.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Hello.cpp
Building target: Hello
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker g++  -o "Hello" 
./src/Hello.o    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  
"___emutls_v._ZSt11__once_call", referenced from:
      void std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&),
std::__future_base::_State_base* const,
std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >,
std::reference_wrapper<bool> >(std::once_flag&, void
(std::__future_base::_State_base::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&),
std::__future_base::_State_base* const&&,
std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >&&,
std::reference_wrapper<bool>&&) in Hello.o
      void std::call_once<void (std::thread::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread> >(std::once_flag&, void
(std::thread::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread>&&) in
Hello.o   "___emutls_v._ZSt15__once_callable", referenced from:
      void std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&),
std::__future_base::_State_base* const,
std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >,
std::reference_wrapper<bool> >(std::once_flag&, void
(std::__future_base::_State_base::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&),
std::__future_base::_State_base* const&&,
std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >&&,
std::reference_wrapper<bool>&&) in Hello.o
      void std::call_once<void (std::thread::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread> >(std::once_flag&, void
(std::thread::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<std::thread>&&) in
Hello.o
      void std::__once_call_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::__future_base::_State_base::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>&, bool&)>
(std::__future_base::_State_base*,
std::reference_wrapper<std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base,
std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()> >,
std::reference_wrapper<bool>)> >() in Hello.o
      void std::__once_call_impl<std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (std::thread::*)()> (std::reference_wrapper<std::thread>)> >() in
Hello.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2:
error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Hello] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The information at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54806 and https://trac.macports.org/ticket/36093 suggests that this error is due to a bug in the MacPorts version of GCC. According to https://trac.macports.org/ticket/36093#comment:35 this has been fixed as of r98493 of MacPorts. I would expect that your problem would go away if you updated to that revision of the port repository and then reinstalled GCC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Those links have been very helpful in my understanding of the problem. However, I just installed gcc47 for the first time last week and r98493 was from five months ago. Do I need to go back to an older revision?